# Does living near a cell tower decrease your overall exposure to RF?

Tags: radio, electromagnetism, cellphone, mobile

I understand that my mobile phone will increase its RF levels when it struggles to connect with a cell tower/base station due to distance. Also being nearer a cell tower will increase my exposure to RF from the tower.

If I was near a cell tower my phone's RF output may decrease and therefore my overall exposure to RF may decrease despite the gain in RF exposure from the tower.

I guess the results would depend on many variables. Maybe their are some rules-of-thumb so... does living near a cell tower decrease your overall exposure to RF?

BTW I'm not asking whether RF is dangerous to humans.

Comment: I wonder what excitement would ensue if this were asked on [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/). I'm not suggesting a migration, nor a crosspost, mind. :-)

Comment: If you live near a **busy** cell tower, you are exposed to all the communication it's doing with other cell phones besides yours.

Comment: @Kaz last time I calculated, just napkin calculations you get much more radiation from a phone against you then a cell tower and yes, the laughable result we found was that the cell tower being closer reduces your RF absorbed if you are actually keeping a cell phone near you normally. I have been wrong before and the calculation was no where near a real calculation.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh [This would happen](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15776/does-living-near-a-cell-tower-decrease-your-overall-exposure-to-rf).

Comment: Interesting. Considering we are exposed to RF signals pretty much all of the time from a variety of sources, I never would have guessed that the cell phone was "much more" radiation than the tower. I wonder how it compares to other signals types and different frequencies... Does the signal frequency effect the exposure level?

Comment: The cell phone is much closer than the tower, and received power is inversely proportional to squared distance.

Comment: What about the bluetooth/WiFi signals from your computer/router? Granted, I don't wear my computer on my butt (most of the time), but it does spend a good deal of time on my _lap_.

Comment: (GSM) Cell phones have a very strong transmitter compared to bluetooth and wifi; usually about 2.5W in very short bursts. WiFi is limited to 100mW.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier I would like to note here, "exposure" is just relative amount of heating you experience, and I still consider it negligible. The amount of power you can absorb generally goes up with frequency as a higher frequency EM wave will have a large dissipation per unit distance, but the transmitters you can have are limited to negligible output power.